# Finder window, Save As prompt missing sidebar entries

Tags: macos, finder

Check out this screenshot:

[image: Save As dialog]

Why is everything missing in the sidebar? Normally I would see Desktop, Downloads, a custom list of favorite folders, Applications, Library, etc. Suddenly this started happening and it's super annoying because I have to browse everywhere manually on the right side. This is the Save As dialog in Chrome, but it's the same way in a regular Finder window. I'm in OS X Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably accidentally hid the favourites list. If you hover your mouse to the right of the **Favorites** text, you'll see a small *Show* text appear. Click it, and your favourites should reappear.

[image: hover button]

Comment: Usability for the win!

Comment: ARRRRGH yep this worked. I never knew this option was there.

Comment: Yeah, one of the stupider changes made in Lion. Back in 10.6 they had the nice drop-down triangles standard in most UIs.

Comment: Ok, I've got a similar issue except that the entire favorites bar is missing.  I don't even have the 'FAVORITES' text to click on.